# Disable using proxy servers on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, proxy, parental-controls

I want to set up parental controls on a Windows 10 laptop. I am using Microsoft Family Safety for this. However, the child account can go to Edge and there use a free proxy. In that way, all sites can be acccessed.

Is it possible to change the settings of the laptop (for example using the registry) so that it becomes impossible to use a proxy server?

(Note that it is normally possible to just leave the Microsoft Family Safety by going to your account. However, I managed to block the url of Microsoft Family Safety, so that is not a problem anymore.)

I found this:
https://support.opendns.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/222597888-How-to-disable-the-use-of-proxies-to-bypass-DNS-logging

Is this a solution that might work?
However, it seems that it only works for the wifi from a router, so disabling proxies in Windows 10 itself would still be better.

Comment: You could try using a specific product for this?  Sophos Home as one example might give you the control you need with minimal effort.

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look at that